# How Come I Didn't Get The Half-Bounty

Tags: support, bounty

I am not trying to be greedy here. I have answer this [question][1] long ago (probably during private beta). It had 150 rep as a bounty by Nathan and it was never awarded in during the seven day period. The grace period has past by and this is suppose to happen according to [the bounty section in the Help Center](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/help/bounty):

> If you do not award the bounty within 24 hours of the bounty period ending, half the bounty value will be automatically awarded to the top voted answer posted after the bounty start, provided it has a score of at least 2. If no new answer matches this requirement, no reputation will be awarded at all, and the reputation used on the bounty will be lost forever.

Please notice this part for specificly:

> If you do not award the bounty within 24 hours of the bounty period ending, half the bounty value will be automatically awarded to the top voted answer posted after the bounty start, provided it has a score of at least 2.

I have the current highest voted answer with a score of +8 yet I didn't get any of the rep (75 to be exact). The half-bounty was actually awarded to therewillbecoffee's answer instead. That answer has a score of +5 at the moment. So my question is why didn't I get any of the 75 rep? My answer has matched all the requirements listed, so I don't quite understand. Did the OP manually award it?

Comment: I guess so, since he answered his question himself, he chose to award half of it manually to the answer of his choice.

Comment: @therewillbecoffee Bounties don't work like that -- the awarder can't give away half of it. Either you award the full bounty to one answer, or the bounty expires, at which point half of the rep goes to the top voted answer withs core >=2 that was posted after the start of the bounty. [Here's the link](http://coffee.stackexchange.com/help/bounty).

Comment: @abbyhairboat Ahh, I get it now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I recall correctly, I believe you answered the question before Nathan added the bounty. I know that @therewillbecoffee answered after you did.

I think the SE thought process is as follows. If a user attaches a bounty it is because they are not convinced with any of the existing answers. Thus, if the user who added the bounty never awards it, the partial award goes to the best answer that came after the bounty was created.

Comment: I have confirmed this timeline - the bounty started 1/31, a full three days after PythonMaster's answer.

Comment: I will now make a feature request... That is not fair!

Comment: @PythonMaster What's not fair about it? Bounties are set to attract additional answers to what's been posted already. If the person who sets the bounty chooses not to award it, where else should the bounty go than to the highest voted post made during the bounty period?

Comment: That I didn't get the bounty just because I answered the question 3 days before the bounty... But congrats to the guy who got it!

Comment: you didn't **automatically** get the bounty. The bounty owner could have awarded it to you, but chose not to. The system only auto-awards to new answers, assuming they got some upvotes.